# How to update and remove list of elements / item from a multivalued array list using java?

Tags: java, arraylist, crud

**Here's a sample code ,**

```
*ArrayList<Movie> list = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        
        list.add(new Movie("Force Awakens", 8.3, 2015));
        list.add(new Movie("Star Wars", 8.7, 1977));
        list.add(new Movie("Empire Strikes Back", 8.8, 1980));
        list.add(new Movie("Return of the Jedi", 8.4, 1983));*

/* etc.... */

*for (Movie empl :list) {
                System.out.println(empl);
        }*
```

**my array list will be like (output in console(eclipse)):**

> Movie [rating=8.7, name=Star Wars, year=1977]
>
> Movie [rating=8.8, name=Empire Strikes Back, year=1980]
>
> Movie [rating=8.4, name=Return of the Jedi, year=1983]
>
> Movie [rating=8.3, name=Force Awakens, year=2015]

**so my question is how to update & delete any one of the above item from list using java. what logic should i apply here.????**

**P.S : i tried java remove() command but thrown me an exception below :**

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
> at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:937)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:891)   at
> mypackage.MainModule.main(MainModule.java:45)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **ConcurrentModificationException** occurs when an object is tried to be modified concurrently when it is not permissible. This exception usually comes when one is working with Java Collection classes (ArrayList in your case).

1- Use `Collections.synchronizedList()` to get a thread-safe version of your list:

```
List<Movie> list = Collections.synchronizedList(yourMoviesArray);
```

Then use an iterator while going through the list and call the `remove()` method on the iterator to remove an item:

```
Iterator<Movie> it = list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
   if(condition) {
       it.remove();
   }
}
```

2- Use A thread-safe variant of ArrayList is `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Movie> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(); 
list.add(); // add all your movies just like you add in a normal list

// conditional remove elemnts 
list.forEach(e -> {
   if (shouldRemove(e))
    list.remove(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using lambda expressions.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class Movie {
    private String name;
    private Double rate;
    private Integer year;
}
```

```
class MovieCRUD {

    @Test
    public void deleteTest() {

        ArrayList<Movie> list = new ArrayList<Movie>();

        list.add(new Movie("Force Awakens", 8.3, 2015));
        list.add(new Movie("Star Wars", 8.7, 1977));
        list.add(new Movie("Empire Strikes Back", 8.8, 1980));
        list.add(new Movie("Return of the Jedi", 8.4, 1983));

        /*Equivalent to deleting star wars*/
        List<Movie> newList = list.stream()
                .filter(movie -> !movie.getName().equals("Star Wars"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());//Only elements whose condition returns true will be retained

        /*
         * Movie(name=Force Awakens, store=8.3, year=2015)
         * Movie(name=Empire Strikes Back, store=8.8, year=1980)
         * Movie(name=Return of the Jedi, store=8.4, year=1983)
         */
        newList.forEach(System.out::println);

    }

   
    @Test
    public void updateTest() {

        ArrayList<Movie> list = new ArrayList<Movie>();

        list.add(new Movie("Force Awakens", 8.3, 2015));
        list.add(new Movie("Star Wars", 8.7, 1977));
        list.add(new Movie("Empire Strikes Back", 8.8, 1980));
        list.add(new Movie("Return of the Jedi", 8.4, 1983));


        List<Object> newList = list.stream()
                .map(movie -> movie.getRate() == 8.8 ? movie.setRate(7.8) : movie)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        /*
         *
         *   Movie(name=Force Awakens, store=8.3, year=2015)
         *   Movie(name=Star Wars, store=8.7, year=1977)
         *  Movie(name=Empire Strikes Back, store=7.8, year=1980) //Updated the movie's ratings
         *  Movie(name=Return of the Jedi, store=8.4, year=1983)
         */
        newList.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

Lambda expressions are very useful for filtering data in sets or arrays.